# I did Name Entity Recognition ( NER) in open nlp, I want to export that data into excel

Tags: nlp

I did Name Entity Recognition ( NER) in open nlp, I want to export that data into excel.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search would have lead you to how to write data to csv file.. but below is an example of how to write your data to csv

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    #Write each rows
    writer.writerow(['1', 'Sam', 'Male'])
    writer.writerow(['2', 'Becky', 'Female'])
    writer.writerow(['3', 'Debby', 'Female'])
    writer.writerow(['4', 'John', 'Male'])
    writer.writerow(['5', 'Richard', 'Male'])
    writer.writerow(['6', 'Kenny', 'Male'])
```